# Arguments not optional in VB6

Tags: listview, ms-access, vb6, runtime-error

Why am I getting this error?

```vb
    Private Sub loadEmployee()
    With frmEmployee.lvEmployee.ListItems
    Call connect
    'SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblemployee "
    Rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tblemployee ", Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
      If Not Rs.EOF Then
        Rs.MoveLast
        Set Item = lvEmployee.ListItems.Add(1, , Rs!id)
            Item.SubItems(2) = Rs!firstname
            'Item.SubItems(2) = Rs!middlename
            Item.SubItems(3) = Rs!lastname
            Item.SubItems(4) = Rs!agename
            Item.SubItems(5) = Rs!gender
            Item.SubItems(6) = Rs!address
            Item.SubItems(7) = Rs!datehired
            Item.SubItems(8) = Rs!birthdate
            Item.SubItems(9) = Rs!birthplace
            Item.SubItems(10) = Rs!citizenship
            Item.SubItems(11) = Rs!cellno
            Item.SubItems(12) = Rs!Status
            Item.SubItems(13) = Rs!basicsalary
            Item.SubItems(14) = Rs!designation
            Item.SubItems(15) = Rs!department
            'Item.SubItems(16) = Rs!m_name
            'Item.SubItems(17) = Rs!m_occupation
            'Item.SubItems(18) = Rs!n_spouse
            'Item.SubItems(19) = Rs!dependents
            'Item.SubItems(20) = Rs!SSS
            'Item.SubItems(21) = Rs!PHILHEALTH
            'Item.SubItems(22) = Rs!PAGIBIG
            Item.EnsureVisible
      End If
      Rs.Close
      Conn.Close
      Set Conn = Nothing
     End With
    End Sub
```

ERROR: `Arguments not optional`

This error comes when I call the function. I called it like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
loadEmployee
End Sub
```

"Private sub..." is highlighted yellow, and "Item=" is highlighted blue.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you declare the `Item`?

Try declaring:

```
Dim Item as listitems
```

Comment: @HandyMannyand ALWAYS use `Option Explicit`! It would have flagged this error up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

it lacks to declare a value, example I created a method with 12 values ​​I have to reference the same values ​​in the method call.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).